# Not able to set property value from XML view for Formatted Text control

Tags: sapui5

My XML code which throwing error

```
<FormattedText htmlText="<h1>Welcome</h1>" id="ft"/>
```

**With this below way adding data from controller it is working fine**

```
<FormattedText id="ft"/>

onAfterRendering : function(){
    this.getView().byId("ft").setHtmlText("<h1>Welcome from controller</h1>")
}
```

> Can somebody explain what is the reason behind this difference of working for this control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an XML file is parsed, **certain characters have a special (that is, high priority)** meaning to the XML parser. When such characters are encountered, they are always interpreted to be part of the XML definition itself and not part of any other content that might exist within the XML document.

As soon as the XML parser encounters one of these high-priority characters (in this case, a less-than (<) character), it will always be interpreted as the start of a new XML tag – irrespective of any other meaning that character might have within the context of the expression. This is known as a **syntax collision**.

You can read about this [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/5cff8d1c3fb84c5db7a00f2daca125af)